# Search ArrayList for certain character in string

Tags: java, arrays, search, arraylist, replace

*What is the correct syntax for searching an `ArrayList` of strings for a single character?  I want to check each string in the array for a single character.
Ultimately I want to perform multiple search and replaces on all strings in an array based on the presence of a single character in the string.
I have reviewed java-examples.com and java docs as well as several methods of searching ArrayLists.  None of them do quite what I need.
P.S. Any pointers on using some sort of file library to perform multiple search and replaces would be great.*

**--- Edit ---**

As per MightyPork's recommendations `arraylist` revised to use simple `string` type.  This also made it compatible with hoosssein's solution which is included.

---

```
public void ArrayInput() {
    String FileName;                            // set file variable
    FileName = fileName.getText();              // get file name

    ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();       // create arraylist

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName)); // create reader
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.length() > 0) {                         // don't include blank lines
                line = line.trim();                         // remove whitespaces
                fileContents.add(line);                     // add to array
            }
        }

        for (String row : fileContents) {
            System.out.println(row);        // print array to cmd
        }

        String oldstr;
        String newstr;

        oldstr = "}";
        newstr = "!!!!!";

        for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.size(); i++) {
            if(fileContents.contains(oldstr)) {
                fileContents.set(i, fileContents.get(i).replace(oldstr, newstr));
            }
        }   

        for (String row : fileContents) {
            System.out.println(row);        // print array to cmd
        }
                                // close file
    }

    catch (IOException ex) {    // E.H. for try
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found.  Check name and directory.");
    }           
}
```

Comment: You would need to iterate over the list manually, and perform the search and replace.

Comment: It would be great if you could show us what you did so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to iterate the list and search for that character

```
string.contains("A");
```

for replacing the character you need to keep in mind that String is immutable and you must replace new string with old string in that list

so the code is like this

```
public void replace(ArrayList<String> toSearchIn,String oldstr, String newStr ){
    for(int i=0;i<toSearchIn.size();i++){
        if(toSearchIn.contains(oldstr)){
            toSearchIn.set(i, toSearchIn.get(i).replace(oldstr, newStr));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use this with an `ArrayList<String[]>` I get a "_cannot find symbol_" on the "_method replace(String,String)_" error.

Comment: But this doesn't work for searching and replacing only part of a string.  Unless there's a simple adjustment I'm not familiar with.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already answered your own question at this point, but with regard to "unless there's a simple adjustment...", simply temporarily store part of the string, then concatenate the new ending to that part and replace the old string with the whole thing. You can get a substring by doing *stringVariable*.subString(*startingIndex*, *endingIndex*).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, modify as needed:

```
public static ArrayList<String> findInString(String needle, List<String> haystack) {
    ArrayList<String> found = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String s : haystack) {
        if(s.contains(needle)) {
            found.add(s);
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

(to search char, just do `myChar+""` and you have string)

---

To add the find'n'replace functionality should now be fairly easy for you.

---

Here's a variant for searching `String[]`:

```
public static ArrayList<String[]> findInString(String needle, List<String[]> haystack) {
    ArrayList<String[]> found = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    for(String fileLines[] : haystack) {
        for(String s : fileLines) {
            if(s.contains(needle)) {
                found.add(fileLines);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return found;
}
```

Comment: note that I'm using an 'ArrayList<String[]>' so, (as far as I can tell) this syntax won't work.

Comment: It will work, if you don't split the file to lines. Or, if you insist on string arrays, what prevents you from adding an extra loop to my code to go through the lines?

Comment: It has something to do with using a 'String' type to search through a 'String[]' type 'arraylist,' ...I think.  It's giving mismatched types errors (even with a variety of modifications).  How would adding an extra loop effect that?  And, yes the file needs to be loaded into the array by line.  (I'm not sure I'm understanding your comment.)

Comment: I don't know why you need to load the file as `String[]`, it seems to only complicate all your work. Anyway, I added an example for `String[]`.

Comment: You're right, esp. with some of the end results I need, it's simpler to use `string` type over `string[].`

Answer (score 1):

For the search and replace you are better off using a dictionary, if you know that you will replace `Hi` with `Hello`. The first one is a simple search, here with the index and the string being returned in a Object[2], you will have to cast the result. It returns the first match, you were not clear on this.

```
public static Object[] findStringMatchingCharacter(List<String> list,
        char character) {

    if (list == null)
        return null;
    Object[] ret = new Object[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        String s = list.get(i);
        if (s.contains("" + character)) {
            ret[0] = s;
            ret[1] = i;
        }
                    return ret;
    } 
    return null;
}

public static void searchAndReplace(ArrayList<String> original,
        Map<String, String> dictionary) {
    if (original == null || dictionary == null)
        return;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.size(); i++) {
        String s = original.get(i);
        if (dictionary.get(s) != null)
            original.set(i, dictionary.get(s));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Another way by using iterator

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Naman");
        list.add("Aman");
        list.add("Nikhil");
        list.add("Adarsh");
        list.add("Shiva");
        list.add("Namit");
        Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String next = iterator.next();
            if (next.startsWith("Na")) {
                System.out.println(next);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over lines twice to do what you need. You can make replacement when iterating over file.

Java 8 solution

```
 try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("pom.xml"))) {
        reader
            .lines()
            .filter(x -> x.length() > 0)
            .map(x -> x.trim())
            .map(x -> x.replace("a", "b"))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    } catch (IOException e){
        //handle exception
    }
```